# jquery get table td values using click handler

Tags: jquery

I need to get values out of a table for specific row. I have a click handler which works, but now need to get the data from the table into an corresponding input fields. The click handler is set to the tr element on a specific table.
I've tried something like this but it's not happy. I can save the ID of the tr in a variable and do something like `$(var + 'tr#someID'). ...` (if that'll work), but there must be a better way?
Anyway, this is what I was trying intially

```
<script>
$('table#someID tr').on('click', function(e){


    console.log($(this + 'td#SomeID').text());
});
```

perhaps using the next/find functions is the best answer here?

edit: if I try `console.log($(this, 'td#SomeID').text());`

it logs everything in the tr which isn't what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate an object (`this`) with a string, which won't work. Try:

```
$('table#someID').on('click', 'tr', function(e){
    console.log($(this).children('td#SomeID').text());
});
```